# How to publish dependency to gitlab repository from CI/CD (403 Forbidden)?

Tags: java, maven, gitlab

I'm trying to public a test project to its repository, but receiving a `403 FORBIDDEN`. What could be the problem?

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: maven:3.8.4-eclipse-temurin-11

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script: mvn deploy -s ci_settings.xml
```

`ci_settings.xml`:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>gitlab-maven</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpHeaders>
          <property>
            <name>Job-Token</name>
            <value>${CI_JOB_TOKEN}</value>
          </property>
        </httpHeaders>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

`pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Result.

> [INFO] Uploading to gitlab-maven:
> https://my.company.com/api/v4/projects/295/packages/maven/com/example/my-test/1.0.0/my-commons-1.0.0.pom

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy
> (default-deploy) on project my-commons: Failed to deploy artifacts:
> Could not transfer artifact com.example:my-commons:jar:1.0.0 from/to
> gitlab-maven: authorization failed for
> https://my.company.com/api/v4/projects/295/packages/maven/com/example/my-test/1.0.0/my-commons-1.0.0.jar,
> status: 403 Forbidden -> [Help 1]

Comment: Better use a repository manager instead of the gitlab repository...

Comment: Sorry, but that's not the question. At all, I only need 3-4 custom libraries to store in gitlab. Adding a custom repo manager is way over the top, if gitlab already supports this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **Repository** section was not enabled for the project:

Settings > General > Visibility, project features, permissions > Packages > Check!